# count the total number of duplicates for each duplicated observation in SAS

Tags: sas, duplicates, proc

I have the following data; basically, some patients have more than one record.

....

I would like to have a variable "count" which is the total number of duplicates. **like below**

[image]

but code I have now and the results:

```
data grouped;
    set have;
    by id notsorted;
    retain count;
    if first.id then count=1;
    else count+1;
    run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This add a count total to each record. In this case, SQL is better here.

```
proc sql;
create table grouped as 
select *, count(*) as count
from have
group by id;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Don't know it is just that simple.